# Processing syslog output to csv with python

Tags: python, hadoop, syslog

I need help with taking log events from my siem and processing them into a csv file that can be ingested into hadoop for further processing. Below is sample from the siem and the desired result. I'm working in python but I'm not as experienced as i need to be.

```
Apr 22 11:52:28 siem <159>Apr 22 11:55:26 10.1.1.10 LEEF:1.0|Websense|Security|7.7.3|transaction:permitted|sev=1       cat=9   usrName=LDAP://10.10.10.10 OU=Standard Users,OU=Users,OU=Frostbyte Falls,OU=Frostbyte - QSD,OU=CDG,OU=North America,DC=Global,DC=bullwinke,DC=com/Mr. Moose  src=10.1.10.10        srcPort=62133   srcBytes=233    dstBytes=39469  dst=165.254.42.233   dstPort=80  proxyStatus-code=200    serverStatus-code=304   duration=0 method=GET       disposition=1048  contentType=application/zip     reason=-        policy=role-8**US Frostbyte        role=8  userAgent=IPM url=http://acroipm.adobe.com/10/rdr/ENU/win/nooem/none/message.zip
```

Hive column definitions: date time logsource user srcIP srcPort dstIP dstPort method payload

Desire format in csv:

```
Apr 22, 11:55:26, 10.1.1.10, Mr. Moose, 10.1.10.10, 62133, 165.254.42.233, 80, GET, url=http://acroipm.adobe.com/10/rdr/ENU/win/nooem/none/message.zip
```

Thoughts?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Peter Varo that you probably want to use a better format if possible. But if you have to parse the data produced by something else… well, you have to parse it.

If you want to do it by regex, I would strongly suggest either matching entire lines, or parsing line by line, instead of collecting all of the dates, then all of the times, etc. For example:

```
import csv
import re

r = re.compile(r'''(?x)
                >(?P<date>\w\w\w\s\d\d) \s
                (?P<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \s
                (?P<logsource>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) \s
                .*?
                DC=com/(?P<user>.*?) \s+
                src=(?P<srcIP>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) \s+
                srcPort=(?P<srcPort>\d+) \s+ .*?
                dst=(?P<dstIP>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) \s+
                dstPort=(?P<dstPort>\d+) \s+ .*?
                method=(?P<method>\w+) \s+ .*?
                url=(?P<url>.*(?!\s))
                ''')

with open(logpath) as logfile, open(csvpath, 'w') as csvfile:
    csv.writer(csvfile).writerows(r.findall(logfile))
```

However, your log format appears to be one well-defined formated crammed inside another crammed inside another. In other words, you've got a typical syslog format of `TIMESTAMP SOURCE <PID>MESSAGE`, and then the `MESSAGE` is some kind of thing with an LDAP URL in the middle, and so on. There are well-known regexes (or other parsers) for at least some of these things, so why write them all from scratch?

Comment: Oh, it is a lot nicer, than mine. Thanks for posting this +1

Comment: But for example yours won't find `June 22` since, you used `\w\w\w`

Comment: @PeterVaro: The OP's format almost certainly won't _have_ `June 22`, so that's not a problem. But that brings up the main point: You need to know the format of what you're trying to parse, not guess at it from a single example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **you should choose a better serialised output**, because string processing in this case is very *dangeroues*, and also not as effective as you wish.

However, I made some regex  catchings for your problem, which are all lists, but I guess from there, you can decide how, and what string data you would like to access, and you can always do `','.join(<list here>)` at the end for joining items in a list with comma..

**BUT as I mentioned above, I do not recommend you this solution**, you should catch this data differently from the source..

```
import re

string = 'Apr 22 11:52:28 siem <159>Apr 22 11:55:26 10.1.1.10 LEEF:1.0|Websense|Security|7.7.3|transaction:permitted|sev=1       cat=9   usrName=LDAP://10.10.10.10 OU=Standard Users,OU=Users,OU=Frostbyte Falls,OU=Frostbyte - QSD,OU=CDG,OU=North America,DC=Global,DC=bullwinke,DC=com/Mr. Moose  src=10.1.10.10        srcPort=62133   srcBytes=233    dstBytes=39469  dst=165.254.42.233   dstPort=80  proxyStatus-code=200    serverStatus-code=304   duration=0 method=GET       disposition=1048  contentType=application/zip     reason=-        policy=role-8**US Frostbyte        role=8  userAgent=IPM url=http://acroipm.adobe.com/10/rdr/ENU/win/nooem/none/message.zip'

dates = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+:\d+:\d+)\s', string)
ip = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', string)
url = re.findall(r'url=.*(?!\s)', string)
dstport = re.findall(r'dstPort=(\d+)', string)
srcport = re.findall(r'srcPort=(\d+)', string)
method = re.findall(r'method=(\w+)\s', string)
user = re.findall(r'DC=com/(.*)\ssrc=', string)

print dates, ip, url, dstport, srcport, method, user
```

Comment: This only solves the first half of the OP's problem. The second half is trivial with the `csv` module (as in one call to `writerows(zip(dates, ip, blah blah))`, but you should still show it, as I'm not sure it'll be trivial to the OP.

Comment: More importantly, I think it would be much, much better to parse the log row by row, than to parse it "column by column" like this.